# Python: how to make variables declared in loops be invisible from outside?

Tags: python, cycle

I have to write non-reusable scripts for statistical calculations. Their writing looks like "gaze at the plots and add/remove 5 lines more". I have a problem: when the code grows to a couple of screen-scrolls, it becomes difficult to write it, because the **namespace is polluted by the variables declared into the loop bodies.**

I know, that Python loops are not code blocks, I know, that Guido van Rossum thinks, that I must move the cycle bodies to functions and methods. But in my case is will not simplify the changes in the code, but will even make it harder.

Now I use a dummy class declaration as the loop body, but, maybe, you know a better way?

```
#what I use now

outer = 7, 40
for elm in outer:
    class Dummy:
        print elm * 2
        temp = elm * 3 #I don't want to see this outside my loops!

# print "temp", temp # should give error
```

Comment: How do separate functions with clear defined purposes make things harder? You can always `del varname` if their purpose has been served.

Comment: By "cycle" you mean "loop"?

Comment: >> How do separate functions with clear defined purposes make things harder?

The situation is such, that I often don't know the future structure of my program. If I will add some functions, I should kill them and add new ones just at the next step. I cannot provide any analysis and design for a one-time calculation script. It's just a good alternative for MATLAB workpad.

Comment: Let's assume for a second you indeed never have to re-visit any of this code after you wrote it and ran it once. I still don't get why writing the same code inside a function rather than at module level is hard. Write code as usual, select it, hit tab, write `def spam():` on top, done.

Comment: When the function body is more than a couple of lines, it is sometimes difficult to switch between the place of its declaration and the place of its usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can always delete names from the global namespace again:

```
outer = 7, 40
for elm in outer:
    print elm * 2
    temp = elm * 3

del temp
```

but really, use functions to fill specific tasks. It *will* make your code more maintainable and easier to read.

Comment: I rarely need to mantain this code anymore. I need to write it once - and forget forever. Of course, if I have something reusable, I do it in normal way, but it is not this case.

These are just one-time calculation scripts. A good alternative to MATLAB workpad and nothing more. Alas, I need the code to be easier to write.

Comment: @Felix Hehe, you're funny. You never write once and forget forever. You write once, tweak a bit, let it run a while, read for ages, fix a bug, let it run a while, refer back to it on your next similar project, read a lot... ad infinum.

Comment: Jh, it's not bugfixing: we often don't know the right way to make it work properly. So I tweak the script more and more. When there appear some robust or reusable pieces of code, we move it to functions and methods, but it may be at the very end of the scripting.

Comment: >> delete names from the global namespace again:

Maybe, it can be simpler to write dumpLocalNames() and deleteNewLocals() functions. But maybe there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: @Felix: `globals()` gives you access to the global namespace; dump the keys, then later on delete straight from the dictionary; `del globals()['temp']` does the same thing as `del temp` in a module-level context.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Martjin 's reply, and based on your suggestion of Matlab's workpad, here is an alternate solution that you can look forward.

The Solution

```
>>> from Workpad import Workpad
>>> with Workpad() as workpad:
    for elm in outer:
        print elm * 2
        workpad.temp = elm * 3
        workpad.temp1 = workpad.temp / 2
        print workpad.temp, workpad.temp1


14
21 10
80
120 60
>>> workpad.temp

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#335>", line 1, in <module>
    workpad.temp
AttributeError: Workpad instance has no attribute 'temp'
```

To make the above work you need to create one Module named `Workpad.py` and place it in your import path

```
class Workpad:
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for e in dir(self):
            if not e in self.__attribs and e != '_Workpad__attribs':
                delattr(self, e)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __init__(self):
        self.__attribs = dir(Workpad)
```

The reason I like this solution is, it does what is intended to do, that is create a scope. Generally Using Class or Function to create scope can be misleading and cumbersome if you need to nest multiple scopes.